# How do you change the playback tempo of the score in MuseScore 4?

Tags: tempo, musescore

I'm really struggling to find the way the playback tempo should be changed in MuseScore 4. I tried googling it but still no luck.

Comment: This [documentation](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/tempo#playback) seems relevant. Note the point that settings in the "play panel" can (temporarily) modify playback tempo.

Comment: @AndyBonner that's documentation for MuseScore 3

Comment: Here, then: [tempo](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/4/setting-your-score#tempo) and [playback](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/4/playback-controls#play-position-and-tempo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First, select a note at the point in the score that you want the tempo marking to go.
2. Then, open the *Tempo palette* and click on the tempo marking that has the right beat value, for example "crotchet=80".
   This will place the tempo marking above the note you selected.
3. To change the BPM value, double click on the number in the tempo marking that you just placed, type in a different number and then click away.
4. If you want to hide the marking, you can deselect "visible" in the properties panel.

---

As seen in the [documentation](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/4/playback-controls), there is another way to adjust the playback tempo:

- Undock the *Play toolbar* (by dragging the rectangle of dots).
  This reveals a slider for playback position, and a slider for Tempo %.

Comment: Wow - yeah, undocking worked but I never would have guessed that. I spent a lot of time looking for this. Wish they hadn't needlessly made it so complicated.